# Is there an integrated way of sending console log to cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'd like to send the console output from some EC2 instances to cloudwatch. Specifically I'm interested in the `cloud-init` output. Is there some standard way to do it in AWS configuration?

I know I can install a daemon on the instance which will forward that data, but I'd rather use a generic solution in cloudformation if possible.

Comment: I think you mean CloudWatch Logs vs CloudTrail, as CloudTrail is only for AWS API access.

Comment: @JasonMartin yes, I did; thanks for spotting that :)